# How you pass CLI arguments in php while booting up the server through terminal?

Tags: php, xampp, php-7

I am getting little trouble in passing arguments and options while booting up the server through `php -S localhost:5000` like this.

The documentation shows passing `--` and then right arguments after this like :

`php -S localhost:5000 -- foo=bar`.

But this above thing is giving me errors like `foo=bar not found in C:\xampp\Pear\`.

I want to pass two CLI arguments which I can read from `stdin` or  from `options` but its not taking arguments. Apart from this how would we even pass options eg `--testing` when we boot up server in specific directory as mentioned above.

like eg `php -S localhost:5000 --testing` How can we pass this testing flag. Same error I am getting when trying to pass flags like these.

Comment: `--` will only work on Linux machine I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use ENV variables instead? It's dead simple solution that should work everywhere.

```
$ FOO=bar php -S localhost:5000
```

In your PHP file then just use then `$_ENV['FOO']`. Done.

Comment: No I don't want to use environment. I only want to use arguments.